# comparing two colums in sqlserver and returing the remaining data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. First one is student table where he can select two optional courses and other table is current semester's optional courses list.

When ever the student selects a course, row is inserted with basic details such as roll number, inserted time, selected course and status as "1". When ever a selected course is de-selected the status is set as "0" for that row.

Suppose the student has select course id 1 and 2.

Now using this query

```
select SselectedCourse AS [text()] FROM  Sample.dbo.Tbl_student_details where var_rollnumber = '020803009' and status = 1 order by var_courseselectedtime desc FOR XML PATH('')
```

This will give me the result as "12" where 1 is physics and 2 is social.

the second table holds the value from 1-9
For e.g course id

```
1 = physics
2 = social
3 = chemistry
4 = geography
5 = computer
6 = Spoken Hindi
7 = Spoken English
8 = B.EEE
9 = B.ECE
```

now the current student has selected 1 and 2. So on first column, i get "12" and second column i need to get "3456789"(remaining courses). 
How to write a query for this?

Comment: What happens if, in 6 months time, an additional optional course is added (such that single digits no longer suffice)? Why are you packing this information into a single column?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: You are right. But this is a demo application  which was asked us to solve in SQL class today.

Comment: @Gaan_setaglA - Well, your status can have two values, that should be enough to be able to work it out. I assume the statement you've used was already given to you so I'm not sure what you are supposed to learn from this. Beware that it's easy to learn the **wrong** thing from this. This design is **not** something to be used in a production environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not in single query but is simple.

---

```
DECLARE @STUDENT AS TABLE(ID INT, COURSEID INT)
DECLARE @SEM AS TABLE (COURSEID INT, COURSE VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @STUDENT VALUES(1, 1)

INSERT INTO @STUDENT VALUES(1, 2)

INSERT INTO @SEM VALUES(1, 'physics')

INSERT INTO @SEM VALUES(2, 'social')

INSERT INTO @SEM VALUES(3, 'chemistry')

INSERT INTO @SEM VALUES(4, 'geography')

INSERT INTO @SEM VALUES(5, 'computer')

INSERT INTO @SEM VALUES(6, 'Spoken Hindi')

INSERT INTO @SEM VALUES(7, 'Spoken English')

INSERT INTO @SEM VALUES(8, 'B.EEE')

INSERT INTO @SEM VALUES(9, 'B.ECE')

DECLARE @COURSEIDS_STUDENT VARCHAR(100), @COURSEIDS_SEM  VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @COURSEIDS_STUDENT = COALESCE(@COURSEIDS_STUDENT, '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), COURSEID) + ' ' FROM @STUDENT

SELECT @COURSEIDS_SEM = COALESCE(@COURSEIDS_SEM , '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), COURSEID) + ' ' FROM @SEM WHERE COURSEID NOT IN (SELECT COURSEID FROM @STUDENT)


SELECT @COURSEIDS_STUDENT COURSEIDS_STUDENT, @COURSEIDS_SEM COURSEIDS_SEM
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
;WITH CTE as (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 0)) as rn,* from Sample.dbo.Tbl_student_details)

,CTE1 As(
select rn,SselectedCourse ,replace(stuff((select ''+courseid  from course_details for xml path('')),1,1,''),SselectedCourse,'') as rem from CTE a 
where rn = 1
union all
select c2.rn,c2.SselectedCourse,replace(rem,c2.SselectedCourse,'') as rem 
from CTE1 c1 inner join CTE c2
on c2.rn=c1.rn+1

)

select STUFF((select ''+SselectedCourse from CTE1 for xml path('')),1,0,''),(select top 1 rem from CTE1 order by rn desc)
```